# Making dictionary more functional

Tags: python, dictionary, functional-programming

how can i change the code, to make it more functional (change the for loop for the same result only to make it shorter in 2 sentences)?

```
def get_language_from_text():
    """
    Simply return an array with the predicted languages.
    """
    resultSet = []
    inputdata = request.data
    #print(inputdata)
    inputdataparsed = json.loads(request.data)
    array_of_sentences = inputdataparsed['inputdata']

    for obj_in_array in array_of_sentences:
        obj_in_array_tmp = obj_in_array
        sentence = obj_in_array['TEXT']
        obj_type = obj_in_array['TYPE']
        obj_lang = obj_in_array['LANGUAGE']
        prediction = detect(sentence)

        result_to_safe = {"TEXT":sentence, 
                            "TYPE": obj_type,
                            "LANGUAGE":obj_lang,
                            "PREDICTED_LANGUAGE": prediction}
        resultSet.append(result_to_safe)
        break
    print(resultSet)
```

Comment: You use most of the local variables only once (or not at all), you don't need them.

Comment: Your code will only ever [try to] process the first element in array_of_sentences and no more. Can you see why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine, it could use a bit of cleaning but that's okay.

You can shorten your loop to:

```
def make_dict(sentence_dict):
    return {
        "TEXT": sentence_dict["TEXT"],
        "TYPE": sentence_dict["TYPE"],
        "LANGUAGE": sentence_dict["LANGUAGE"],
        "PREDICTED_LANGUAGE": detect(sentence_dict["TEXT"])
    }

result_set = [ make_dict(sentence_dict) for sentence_dict in array_of_sentences ]
```

You can make this more functional by mapping `make_dict` over `array_of_sentences` as follows:

```
result_set = list(map(make_dict, array_of_sentences))
```